# Images don't show in drupal

Tags: image, drupal

I've created some styles in Drupal 7 and I used them for image fields in my content types. But the images don't show in default article type or in views.

What is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to provide further info I'm afraid.

Where are you outputting them and how?

Can you see the images OK in the CMS?

Are you getting any output?

Have you cleared the cache(s)?

Comment: 1.I upload images in ImagesField when I publish new content.2.Also images don't show When I upload Image for imagefiled in CMS. Although the images that I've upload exists in host but when I click image URL that image doesn't exist.3.Yes,I've got output by publishing new content but doesn't work.4.Yes,I've cleared caches.i mention that before it works correctly and host permissions is as default like before.

Comment: Sounds like a configuration issue to me.

I would start by having a look at the link that the CMS spits out to the image.  You say it doesn't show.  It could be that the CMS thinks the image is there (adds a link to it in the database), but the permissions are incorrect on the "images" directory in your configuration.  In this case, they won't upload. 

Try setting permissions on "default/files" to 755 and see if that fixes it.  If it does, you should read the Drupal Permissions documentation.

Answer (score -1):

My problem solved. The `.htacces` file's content had problem and permissions was incorrect.